# Memory limited extension on SVF2

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to implement the MemoryLimited extension in the Forge viewer per [these instructions](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/memory-limit/)

But ever since the switch to SVF2, it doesn't seem like the extension is activating. The progress bar doesn't turn blue like it used to, and large models frequently crash on mobile browsers. Is the MemoryLimited feature still compatible with SVF2? And if so, how do we activate it?

My options code:

```
{
    env: "AutodeskProduction2",
    getAccessToken: _this.getForgeToken,
    api: 'streamingV2'
  }
```

And my config3d:

```
const config = {
loaderExtensions: { svf: 'Autodesk.MemoryLimited' },
memory: {
    limit: 1024
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `Autodesk.MemoryLimited` extension doesn't support svf2 format at this moment. Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: Any plans to support MemoryLimited in the future? I had to roll my app back to the old SVF API because large models would repeatedly crash on mobile devices